# How do I take advantage of Connection Pooling with Apache Active MQ?

Tags: java, jms, connection-pooling, activemq-classic

I'd like to know how to properly use connection pooling with Active MQ.

Currently I have a Connection Factory that creates a new connection every time I want to send a message.

I'd like to be able to pool Connections so I don't incur the overhead of connecting every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use activemq-pool module and PooledConnectionFactory.

See http://activemq.apache.org/spring-support.html for some more info on the topic

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that in the documentation.